# CSS don't let element go outside

Tags: html, css

I have a html list with following items:

```
<ul>
...
<li>Counter party: <span><em>GB15MIDL400515123111145671111111118</em></span></li>
...
</ul>
...
```

The problem is when I visualize this with a smaller screen, the EM value goes outside the borders of my list:

[image]

[image]

What can I do at my css to get the em value inside the borders.

Comment: Maybe shrink the text with `@media` once it reacher certain size (the screen)? Or hide the exctra characters? (css `overflow: hidden`)

Comment: `word-wrap:break-word` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word`

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Counter party: <span><em>GB15MIDL400515123111145671111111118</em></span></li>
</ul>
```

Or `word-break: break-all`

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Counter party: <span><em>GB15MIDL400515123111145671111111118</em></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a width to your paragraph and change the width in diffrent screens with Media Queries

Answer (score 0):

if you want the division with a hyphen at one (or several) particular character/s, you can insert `&shy;` (="soft hyphen"), also several times:

```
<span><em>GB15MIDL&shy;400515123&shy;1111456711&shy;11111118</em></span>
```

This will break the word at the last "`&shy;`" position that still fits into the line. If the line is long enough, you won't see those entities.